# PostgreSQL syntax error in parameterized query on "date $1"

Tags: postgresql, types, prepared-statement, parameter-passing, libpq

Trying to parameterize my SQL queries (using libpq function [PQexecParams](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html)), I was stuck on a syntax error:

```
SELECT date $1
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
```

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I was using PQexecParams, but the point is the same. I tried to address your comments, but feel free to edit the question.

Comment: Your update clarified things. Interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Prepared statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-prepare.html)

The explanation for this can be found [in the chapter **Constants of Other Types** of the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC):

> The `::`, `CAST()`, and function-call syntaxes can also be used to specify
>   run-time type conversions of arbitrary expressions, as discussed in
>   [Section 4.2.9](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS). **To avoid syntactic ambiguity, the *`type 'string'`* syntax
>   can only be used to specify the type of a simple literal constant.**
>   Another restriction on the type *`'string' syntax`* is that it does not
>   work for array types; use `::` or `CAST()` to specify the type of an array
>   constant.

Bold emphasis mine.

Parameters for prepared statements are not actually *sting literals* but typed *values*, so you cannot use the form *`type 'string'`*. Use one of the other two forms to cast the value to a different type, like you found yourself already.

Example:

```
PREPARE foo AS SELECT $1::date;

EXECUTE foo('2005-1-1');
```

#### Similar for [`PQexecParams` in the libpq C library](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html)

The documentation:

> ... In the SQL command text, attach an explicit cast to the parameter
>   symbol to show what data type you will send. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE x = $1::bigint;
> ```
>
> This forces parameter `$1` to be treated as `bigint`, whereas by default
>   it would be assigned the same type as x. Forcing the parameter type
>   decision, either this way or by specifying a numeric type OID, is
>   strongly recommended. ...

The ***alternative***, as mentioned in the quote above, is to pass the OIDs of respective data types with `paramTypes[]` - if you actually need the cast. In most cases it should work just fine to let Postgres derive data types from the query context.

> `paramTypes[]`
>
> Specifies, by OID, the data types to be assigned to the parameter
>   symbols. If `paramTypes` is `NULL`, or any particular element in the array
>   is zero, the server infers a data type for the parameter symbol in the
>   same way it would do for an untyped literal string.

You can get the OID of data types from the system catalog [`pg_type`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-type.html):

```
SELECT oid FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'date';
```

You must use the correct internal type name. For instance: `int4` for `integer`.
Or with a convenience cast to [`regtype`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html#DATATYPE-OID-TABLE):

```
SELECT 'date'::regtype::oid;
```

This is more flexible as known aliases for the type name are accepted as well. For instance: `int4`, `int` or `integer` for `integer`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use a type cast instead of `date`:

```
SELECT $1::date
```

Comment: I spent some considerable time figuring this out :-)

Comment: The answer is interesting, though.

Comment: How and where are you using this statement? This is still invalid SQL if run "as is"